# How to Automatically adjust width in CSS so horizontal scrollbars would adjust automatically without taking so much space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to adjust width of a list  inside a container `(500px, 200px)` automatically. What I want to achieve is something like this 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3QWS/)

But the problem with it is that you need to set the width of the list so that horizontal scrollbars would appear. Is there a work around for it so that the scrollbars would only take enough space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#container ul {white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! Too bad I can't upvote you since I don't have any reputation here! Thanks a lot!